# "Variable expected" error when using Inno Setup StringChangeEx function

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Download Plugin to download a bunch of files for my installation. These files are listed in "`files.json`".

```pascal
FileList := TStringList.Create;
FileList.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\files.json'));
  
for i := 0 to FileList.Count-1 do
begin
  fileName := ExtractFileName(FileList[i]);
  
  StringChangeEx(FileList[i], '\', '/',True);

  //Add each file to download queque
  idpAddFile("www.myapiaddress.com/files/" + FileList[i], ExpandConstant('{tmp}\install\') + fileName );
  Log(FileList[i]);
end;
```

What gives me a headache is the line `StringChangeEx(FileList[i], '\', '/',True)`. As soon as I put that in, the idp.iss stops compiling, giving me the error: `Variable expected` on

```pascal
procedure idpAddFile(url, filename: String);                     external 'idpAddFile@files:idp.dll cdecl';
```

Installer compiles normal, if I remove `StringChangeEx` from my script entirely. It does not help to place it in a different location...

Any idea, what might cause this problem?

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`StringChangeEx` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchangeex) needs a `string` *variable* in the first argument (it's declared as `var`). You are giving it a `string` *value* only.

Your code would work, were `FileList` a `string` *array*. But it's not, it's a class with an array-like `string` default *property*. Using a property value is an equivalent of using a function/method return value. A property is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for getter and setter methods.

You will have to copy the value to a `string` *variable* and back.

```pascal
S := FileList[i];
StringChangeEx(S, '\', '/',True);
FileList[i] := S;
```

*Though you actually do not need to copy it back in your case.*

---

Regarding the reason why the error refers to `idp.iss` file: There seems to be a bug in Inno Setup that makes it report the error as if it had occurred on the very first line of the Pascal Script code (what in your case is the very first real code in the included `idp.iss`). I've posted a [bug report](https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/qZRgSjtk5e4). It was [fixed already](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/5178f8aae8a515a1e18f6e742842f2bb5f277607).